# Android Listview - element's background is going outside the List's rounded corner

Tags: android, listview

I have a Listview, with rounded corners by setting the background as:

```
 <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">        
        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
    </shape>
```

I'm trying to add a background image to the individual Rows in the list:

```
android:background="@drawable/prize_bar"
```

But the first row and last row's background are going outside the rounded corners.

Comment: You might just need to apply a similar style to the first and last rows in your list.